# CardView shadow flicker after going back from shared element transition

Tags: android, kotlin, android-cardview, shared-element-transition

Going back after a shared element transition causes my CardView's shadow to flicker.

I've managed to implement a basic shared element transition with a CardView and a TextView, and it seems to work pretty well except for one thing. When I press the back button and go to the previous activity, the original CardView's shadow sort of flickers for some reason, as you can see [here](https://streamable.com/8vo72).

Code for the transition

```
val intent = Intent(context, TestActivity::class.java)

        val cardTransition = context.getString(R.string.card_transition)
        val textTransition = context.getString(R.string.text_transition)

        val pair1: Pair<View, String> = Pair.create(testCard, cardTransition)
        val pair2: Pair<View, String> = Pair.create(card_text, textTransition)

        val options =
            ActivityOptionsCompat.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(
                context as Activity,
                pair1, pair2
            )
        ActivityCompat.startActivity(context, intent, options.toBundle())
```

And CardViews in XML

```xml
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                android:id="@+id/testCard"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="200dp"
                android:layout_margin="24dp"
                app:cardElevation="40sp"
                android:transitionName="@string/card_transition"
                app:cardCornerRadius="24dp"/>


<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/card_layout"
        app:cardElevation="40sp"
        android:layout_margin="24dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="24dp"
        android:transitionName="@string/card_transition"
        tools:context=".activities.TestActivity"/>
```

Comment: Do you have sollution for this issue?

Comment: No unfortunately, haven't touched Android dev in a while now

Comment: It happens because of `cardElevation`, but I don't know how to prevent it.